# How to modify checkout total in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to modify checkout total. Added my custom rate this rate generate on dynamically wordpress hook

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','test_overwrite_fedex',100,2);
function test_overwrite_fedex($rates,$package) {

foreach ($rates as $rate) {
    var_dump($rates);die();
    //Set the price
    $rate->cost = 1000;

    //Set the TAX
    $rate->taxes[1] = 1000 * 0.2;

}

return $rates;
}
```

Comment: filter must hook like `add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','test_overwrite_fedex',10,2);`,

Comment: using `die();` you will not modyfie anything. write `$rates` into errors log